# SSIS Data Flow How to Remove Duplicate Rows but Log the Duplicates in SSIS

Tags: ssis, duplicates

I learned from [Remove duplicates in SSIS Data Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430282/remove-duplicates-in-ssis-data-flow) how to use the Sort transformation to remove rows with duplicate data values.

In my case, I'm reading a delimited file, need to eliminate the duplicates, *and to log the rows which had the duplicate keys*. I need to output those rows to another delimited file, and will email it back to the customer so they can correct the data and try again.

I can't quite figure out how to do this, though. I'll be experimenting with Aggregate and Merge Join, but I hope there's a known pattern for doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi my answer gonna work with any data, because some solutions in internet need primary key of rows, **for my solution primary key is not required**.
Here sample structure and sample dataset:

```
a   b
1   23
1   23
16  59
12  12
13  45
12  12
45  56
```

[image]

Just group by all columns and add last column - count all (If there are more than two columns or more, you just need in "Aggregate" element put all columns and foreach set group by and in the end put "Count All" column):

[image]

Then just add conditional split element and take all rows where are more than 1 same row:

[image]

Real Example:

[image]

Comment: Pretty good: +1. But what if columns a and b are the key columns, and I also want columns C an D in the result OLE DB Destination?

Comment: BTW, wish I could +10 for the great detail in the answer

Comment: John Saunders  IT Doesn't Matter, if all your columns are keys are not and how many there are columns. **You just need in "Aggregate" element put all columns and foreach set group by** and in the end put "Count All" column. This gonna work.

Comment: Hi @Justin, when you say "for my solution primary key is not required", you are exactly talking about what?, primary key is more a concept, i mean in this case your primary key is column a and b, so i didn't finish to catch at all.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla some solutions in internet required pirmary key - some ID column for the row.... in this case yes this is a concept

Answer (score 2):

I [go through a few options on my blog](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2009/01/eliminating-duplicate-primary-keys-in.html) to remove duplicates from the data flow, with [a little footnote here](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.ca/2009/01/extracting-duplicate-primary-key-rows.html) on how to "save" the duplicate rows for alternate processing.

Answer (score 0):

**It might be possible via scripting.**

First, you would [use a script to iterate through the dataset](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2007/10/14/ssis-design-pattern-read-a-dataset-from-variable-in-a-script-task.aspx) and identify duplicates programmatically. [Then you could write entries to the log file for the dupes that you find](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3916711/Script-Task-and-Event-Logging-in-SSIS.htm).